# How to get Xpath of Pop up message when 'inspect' function for "OK" button is not present

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to delete a record from a web page. I got the xpath of 'delete' icon. Next step: A pop up message comes-"Are you sure you want to delete this record" . I could not find the "inspect" functionally for the "OK" button in pop-up. Hence could not get xpath of it. How can i delete the record?

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "ActionChains".(function for space, enter, tab and so on.)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dev console, you can use this button to click on your element and identify it.

[image]